# What is the difference between "universal" and "generic"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context

I hear lots of time the words `universal` and `generic` being used in similar contexts (especially in software engineering) - what is the difference between them?

Comment: Both are words with a lot of meanings, and in software engineering (a field that didn't even exist even 60 years ago, and whose terminology is therefore completely [metaphoric](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf)) they have both spread out and encompassed more semantic territory, often overlapping. Their original meanings (and both are Latin borrowings) go back centuries and cover most of creation, so etymology is little help. Do you have any ideas about their patterns of use and their intended senses in CE?

Comment: I can't think of a really good "minimal pair" (if indeed there are any). The best I can come up with is that if I had to assign *English* and *Esperanto* to *universal language* and *generic language*, I'd connect them in that order.

Comment: @Fumble In software engineering, [universal code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_(data_compression)) is something quite different from [generic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming).

Comment: @Janus: That's a highly "domain-specific" distinction which doesn't reflect anything that would be meaningful to most native speakers. And I must admit that I didn't really understand *universal code* even after following that Wikipedia link, so I googled **define "universal code"** hoping for more info. But all I found was unrelated stuff about genetics and ethics.

Comment: @Fumble Very true—but it is the domain mentioned in the question, where there is actually a clear, distinct difference between the two words. Outside coding and grammar/syntax/semantics, though, I can't recall the last time I used the word _generic_ at all.

Comment: @Janus: My bad. I didn't notice that specific point in the question. Apart from the contexts you mention, I also refer to *generic painkillers* and *antibiotics*, where I mean they're not specifically relevant to whatever condition they being used to treat (I've no idea whether actual medical people would endorse that usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**universal** implies there is only one kind, or that this works with all kinds.

**generic** implies that of the kinds in existence, this one is an 'average' or even 'minimal' one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Software Engineering *universal* means that the thing is applicable to all cases. Or it can adjust with any requirement needed for the machine/tool. Generics are special data types that mean they can be assigned a type at run time. So *Generics* are not specific. They are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of software, generic is usually used in contrast to trademark names. One speaks of generic drugs, for instance, to refer to drugs not produced by the original maker / developer. As such, it carries a whiff of second class.

Universal usually refers to requirements and applications. A universal power adapter, for instance, works over all of the voltages which one is likely to encounter. If a company had made a reputation by developing and selling the first universal power adapter, then a competitor who develops a cheaper (and perhaps less effective or reliable) version could be said to sell a generic universal power adapter.

Comment: Generic is used widely to denote non-specificity. It is by no means confined predominantly to pharmaceuticals.

Comment: And, if you'll reread my answer, I used drugs as an example. I never stated that the term was restricted, or even confined predominately to pharmaceuticals. And you'll notice that my discussion of universal used an example of a generic device which is not a pharmaceutical. Sheesh.